# I want to view whole site by disabling CSS

Tags: css

I want to view on site by disabling CSS, I don't want open each page and through Firebug to disable it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Pro Webmasters is for questions about sites you control.  Questions about how to make browsers work the way you want are a better fit for Super User.   In this case, a similar  question has already been asked and answered on that site.  See: http://superuser.com/questions/137529/is-there-a-plugin-extension-to-disable-css-on-certain-sites-and-not-others-when

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - Actually this is a common practise for web-developers and designers, to check web-accessibility, I myself use it frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Firefox it's very easy. Just press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to get the traditional main menu, then select `View/Website-style/No style`. The titles could be a little different, because I translated them from my localized browser.

For IE users it is almost the same: press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to get the main menu, and select `View/Format/No format`.

Comment: Hi Martin,ur answer worked best for me,tried above plugins but could not make them workout

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046738/how-to-disable-css-in-browser-for-testing-purposes) and a similar question was asked at [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/137529/is-there-a-plugin-extension-to-disable-css-on-certain-sites-and-not-others-when).  Here is a summary of the best answers:

**[Chandu Venjaramood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1708139/chandu-venjaramood)**: If the [Web Dev Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) is installed, people can use this keyboard shortcuts: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (Mac) and <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (Win)

**[yakunins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/316979/yakunins)**: Install [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/), then add *.css rule in Filters options (custom filters tab). The method affect only on external stylesheets. It doesn't turn off inline styles.

**[Isxek](https://superuser.com/users/2132/isxek)**: This [Firefox Accessibility Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5809) allows you to turn off CSS when needed, and it also allows users to utilize their own stylesheet if needed.

**[ZTD](https://superuser.com/users/65341/ztd)**: ...use Stylish (for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe)). Then get [Stylish-Custom](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/stylish-custom/). ... You can set rules where any particular CSS file will turn on/off depending on what site you are currently viewing.

**[barfoon](https://superuser.com/users/1763/barfoon)**: ...[use] the [personalized web extension for Chrome](http://goo.gl/XivM) to accomplish this. It can block images/CSS for an entire domain every time you visit it.

Answer (score -1):

Try a text only browser like links, w3m or lynx